# How to use 'target' css psuedo-class on html 'name' attribute

Tags: html, css, vba

I'm trying to use the ":target" CSS class to highlight a section of html based on a link clicked that includes an anchor fragment(ex: C:\Desktop\Test.html#link). The regions that are being modified in my document have "name" identity attributes. The target pseudo class worked with "id" attributes for me but am having trouble with "name". Thanks.

PS: The reason I'm using "name" is because I'm writing VBA scripts about HTML documents that were directly converted from MS Word. (Word uses "name" for bookmark conversions to links)

Sample Code I have tried:

```
a:target {
          color: red;
}

a[name = test]:target {
           color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1st CSS is just for styling (how the content looks, layout etc...), use js you can easily update the content (check the example)

> #### CSS describes how HTML elements are to be displayed on screen, paper, or in other media.
>
> [image]

2nd

If you just want to check if the `<a>` element has a `name` attribute, then use `a[name]` (2nd link in my example)

If you need partial match do `a[name*=test]`, any name contains `test` will be selected. (3rd link in my example)

```js
var alltest = document.getElementsByName('test');

alltest.forEach(function(test) {
  test.setAttribute('href', '#newlink');
  test.innerHTML = 'updated link';
});
```

```css
a[name] {
  color: green;
}

a[name*=test] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="google.com">google.com</a><br>
<a name="alsowork" href="google.com">google.com</a><br>
<a name="test" href="google.com">google.com</a>
<a name="test" href="google.com">google.com</a>
<a name="test" href="google.com">google.com</a>
```

Comment: I actually edited my code sample using the ":target" css class. I want to target a specific name and modify it's html contents. The modifying only happens on clicked link event. I included a sample link path in my question.

Comment: Yes, I have a CSS file linked to a HTML file. When a link is clicked that includes an anchor tag at end "#link" I want that linked section of html to be modified. The CSS code will modify HTML content of specific section targeted

Comment: @StevenKligman CSS is just for styling, it does not replace content from HTML etc. For dynamic content you need to use JS

Comment: Oh, ok that makes a lot more sense now. Thanks

Comment: @StevenKligman ok check the updated code, using js to update all link with attribute name = test

Comment: Ok, thanks for the JS code but how come CSS allows for the use of ":target" pseudo class for targeted elements in HTML after a link is clicked?

Comment: @StevenKligman example here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp

Comment: CSS is about how the content looks in different situation, target is one of them. `REF: (#news:target) Selects the current active #news element (clicked on a URL containing that anchor name)`

Comment: Yes, I've been reading about pseudo-classes in CSS but my original question was that it wasn't working with "name" attributes for elements.